# Override fancybox from remote-file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Well, I am using an popup frame and I would like to change some functions of it. But the file is remote file and I am not quite sure how to override javascript functions?

Basically I wanna override this part:

```
<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>
```

Because I want to disable

> hideOnOverlayClick

so instead of true, I want that function on false.

Also, is there any chance when that popup comes up, to run custom javascript timer that will force script close after 30 seconds or so?

Thanks in advance. I hope its possible in both cases.

Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fileice.net/gateway/mygate.php?id=4465766c4278366467523838"></script>
```

That is the gateway that includes fancybox and jquery. It runs on click of a button, so I hope by including that script you can get informations you need?

Update #2:
http://jsfiddle.net/pVp5h/

Comment: This needs more detail and clarification. How exactly is the file being included? How is the plugin being initialized?

Comment: Allright... I will update my post right now ;)

Comment: Your update is not realy usefull, as the script is minfied and encoded and completly unreadable (at least for me). Could you perhaps set up a fiddle, or provide us with a link to the actual page?

Comment: All right... added onclick to run the gateway. -jsfiddle added as sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could just download the javascript file you are using, make the changes you want, and host and reference it again yourself.

**edit:**
just noticed your link, and the file is copyrighted and minified. This means my previous answer is not a good idea... Are you even supposed to use this file?

Comment: Yep... Although I messaged the administrator of the website to tell me how to override the javascript inside of the file, but he barrely comes online so I thought I can ask people arround here... :]